# Run macro on cell being changed by user

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro automatically run if any cells in a range is changed (C5 to c25).

As you see in the code below, it should automatically bring up a message box asking the user whether or not to continue (if the user says yes then runs the macro).

I cannot get the code to start running though once I have changed any one of the cells (from c5 to c25).

Here is the code - it is not all of my own:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("C5:C25")) Is Nothing Then Reminder
End Sub
Sub Reminder()
'
' Reminder Macro 
'
response = MsgBox("Do you want to set a reminder in Outlook for when the next update is required? If yes, make sure your Microsoft Outlook is open.", vbYesNo)

If response = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("You selected 'No'")
    Exit Sub
End If
'Rest of my macro code goes here...

End sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is this code placed in the Worksheet Module? Or an ordinary code module?  In order to invoke the `Change` event handler, it neesd to be in the Worksheet module.

Comment: I think a Worksheet Module..on the left it has: VBAProject (file name) --> then the Microsoft Excel objects then the Modules. This is in Module3

Comment: Module3 is an ordinary code module. See my answer below. Let me know if any questions on how to implement it. Your code works, it's just in the wrong place :)

Comment: Plus double-check you haven't deactivated `Events`. Type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the *Immediate* window of the VBE

Comment: Thank you @DavidZemens it was just in the wrong place - you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your code is in the Worksheet's code module.  From the comments above, you indicate it's in Module 3.  It needs to be moved to the worksheet's code module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Range("C5:C25"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Call reminder
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, make sure you put it in the Worksheet object. Also I believe the code won't be active until you save as an xlsm, close, and reopen.

Comment: This is a comment note an answer - and David Zemens made the same point (as a comment) before you posted this